# Deploy wireless to iPhone using Windows machine

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.ios

Can I deploy my xamarin.iOS app over Wifi from my windows machine?

I only have a remote mac that I use for building, but obviously can't plug in my iPhone there to establish a remote connection. Is there a feature in visual studio or any other possibility to debug wirelessly without the need to purchase a real mac?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to deploy an app to device without a mac ?

Yes, it is . Take a look at [Hot Restart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/deploy-test/hot-restart) .

**However , we need to connect to windows with usb .**

And there are some [limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/deploy-test/hot-restart#limitations) in this way .

---

> Is it possible to deploy an app Wirelessly  ?

Yes , it is ,please  check [Wireless Deployment for Xamarin.iOS and tvOS Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/wireless-deployment?tabs=macos).

Just ensure that your deployment machine and target device are on the same wireless network.

**And the mac is required in this way.**

---

> Is it possible to deploy an app Wirelessly without a mac ?

**No , it is impossible .**

Comment: okay, so everything is as i thought. too bad...
But thanks for your reply :)